# Remove asterisk from a label

Tags: html, css

I am trying to remove an "*" from a label field. how it works is when I select an option "Other" it populates the hidden fields "Additional Comments with an "*" at the comment section.

Also, this "*" drives the submit button as well. if we input information in the comments, then the submit button is visible.

1. I want to remove the "*" symbol from the comment box
2. the submit button would be populated every time and ready for submission

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"     ng-checked="{{itemenable4}}" id="enableButton4" ng-click="c.isChecked(itemenable4)">&nbsp; Other</label><br>
</div>
<div class="comment-box " ng-show="checked">
  <img width="80" style="vertical-align: top;margin-right: 10px;margin-top: 8px;" src={{imageurl}} alt="Additional Comments" />
  <span style="color: #e31d1a; font-size: 22px;position: relative;display: inline-block;top: -87px;left: -2px;" ng-show="feedbackStatus>=1 && feedbackStatus<=3">&#42;</span>
  <textarea id="userComments" rows="4" cols="80" maxlength="255" placeholder={{commentBoxValue}} ng-model="userComments"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
  <button id="submit" type="button" class="submit-button" ng-click="submitEmailFeedback1()" ng-disabled='(userComments.length==0 || userComments==null || userComments==undefined) && (feedbackStatus>=1 && feedbackStatus<=3)'><i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{submitText}}</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add a working demo ? maybe with : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular

Answer (score 0):

We removed the following from HTML.

=1 && feedbackStatus* -->

and took off the following from CSS

```
.submit-button:disabled {
    background: #7F7F7F;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

This resolved the issue